# Custom Django Database Frontend

Tags: python, database, django, frontend

I have been trying to get my head around Django over the last week or two. Its slowly starting to make some sense and I am really liking it.

My goal is to replace a fairly messy excel spreadsheet with a database and frontend for my users. This would involve pulling the data out of a table, presenting it in a web tabular format, and allowing changes to be made through text fields and drop down menus, with a simple update button that will update all changes to the DB.

My question is, will the built in Django Forms functionality be the best solution? Or would I create some sort of for loop for my objects and wrap them around html form syntax in my template? I'm just not too sure how to approach the solution.

Apologies if this seems like an simple question, I just feel like there is maybe a few ways to do it but maybe there is one perfect way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way not to implement you own pages and to have a tabular view of your data is to use the django's built-in admin interface. It gives you sorting, filtering and search functionality and quick to start. You just need to define your models in models.py and setup the admin pages as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/).

Normally the admin page is not used as a representation to users or customers but in the case you described it seems a clean and quick choice.

Comment: I see, and how customizable is it in terms of look? Can I have all records listed down the page in a 1 row = 1 record kind of format?

Comment: yes each row represents one record of the db (or one instance of your model)

Comment: I second this option based on what you have described. Setting up the admin interface is pretty quick and painless;  give it a go and see if it is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Exporting the excel sheet in Django and have the them rendered as text fields , is not as easy as 2 step process.

you need to know how Django works.

First you need to export the data in mysql in database using either some language or some ready made tools.

Then you need to make a Model for that table and then you can use Django admin to edit them

Comment: I have created my model, I am using just a singular table. At the moment I am just using phony data in the table to simulate an actual live record. Data on the old spreadsheet will not be moved over to the database, only new orders will created in the database, old entries will simply fall off the spreadsheet eventually to zero as they are complete. So I have the data and SQL organised I guess its just the pulling out of the data and making it editable by users in a nice clean format similar to excel. Thanks for your responses so far.